# SQL Case Statement COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I need to do a case statement, group the results and count the results in my SQL query.  I have done this so far but not quite sure how to get it to work properly:

```
SELECT 'OS' = 
    CASE
        WHEN OS.Info LIKE 'AIX %' THEN 'Unix'
        WHEN OS.Info LIKE 'LINUX%' THEN 'Unix'
    END, COUNT( 'OS' )
FROM Asset A (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN Asset_IP AIP (NOLOCK) ON A.AssetID = AIP.AssetID AND AIP.LastUpdateDate = (SELECT MAX( Asset_IP.LastUpdateDate ) FROM Asset_IP (NOLOCK) WHERE A.AssetID = Asset_IP.AssetID)
LEFT JOIN Asset_IP_OS AIPOS (NOLOCK) ON AIP.AssetIPID = AIPOS.AssetIPID
LEFT JOIN OSNav OS (NOLOCK) ON AIPOS.OSNavID = OS.OSNavID
GROUP BY OS.Info
ORDER BY OS.Info
```

The OS may come up as AIX 7.0 or AIX 7.2 or Linux 2.3 or Windows 7 or Solaris 10.  All the Unix based OS must be under Unix with a count, etc...  I would like it to show something like this:

```
OS      Count
Unix    200
Windows 1200
```

Comment: On a side-note, please check this: https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `CASE` statement in `Group By` or use derived table to use the Alias name `OS` in `group by` . Since we have removed `OS.Info` in `group by`, we cannot use `OS.Info` in `order by`. Use alias name `OS` in `Order by`

```
SELECT OS = CASE
              WHEN OS.Info LIKE 'AIX %'
                    OR OS.Info LIKE 'LINUX%' THEN 'Unix'
              ELSE 'Others' --default
            END,
       Count(OS.Info)
FROM   Asset A (NOLOCK)
       LEFT JOIN Asset_IP AIP (NOLOCK)
              ON A.AssetID = AIP.AssetID
                 AND AIP.LastUpdateDate = (SELECT Max(Asset_IP.LastUpdateDate)
                                           FROM   Asset_IP (NOLOCK)
                                           WHERE  A.AssetID = Asset_IP.AssetID)
       LEFT JOIN Asset_IP_OS AIPOS (NOLOCK)
              ON AIP.AssetIPID = AIPOS.AssetIPID
       LEFT JOIN OSNav OS (NOLOCK)
              ON AIPOS.OSNavID = OS.OSNavID
GROUP  BY CASE
            WHEN OS.Info LIKE 'AIX %'
                  OR OS.Info LIKE 'LINUX%' THEN 'Unix'
            ELSE 'Others'
          END
ORDER  BY OS
```

**Note :** I have added `else` statement to avoid `NULL's` when expressions are not satisfied..

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.  Just hoping it was a bit simpler.